# get_posts not honoring post_status

Tags: get-posts

I have a custom post type 'license' with custom post statuses 'active,inactive,cancel,expire'. However when I run a get_posts query to get only posts with active status it returns all the posts irrespective of the status.

```
$active_licenses = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'license',
        'post_status'    => 'active',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'ID',
        'order'          => 'DESC',

    ) );
```

I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What does your register_post_status() call look like? Add that to your question too.

Comment: I am using Piklist to create post types and settings pages. Here is the call
$post_types['license'] = array(
     'labels' => piklist('post_type_labels', 'License'),
     'title' => __('Enter a new License'),
     'public' => false,
     'rewrite' => false,
     'query_var' => false,
     'status' => array( 
   'inactive' => array ( 'label' => 'Inactive'),
   'active'   => array ( 'label' => 'Active'),
   'expired'  => array ( 'label' => 'Expired'),
   'cancel'   => array ( 'label' => 'Cancelled')
   )
   );

Comment: I don't know what piklist is, so you should probably ask the author of that code about it.

Comment: Try using `new WP_Query` instead of `get_posts`

Comment: Vijay - it's best to add code to your existing question so it's more readable. Can you add the full code for your reigster_post_status() - also make sure you've flushed your permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try use `'perm' => 'readable'` in your query arguments to make sure `WP_Query` runs a permissions check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register the custom post status](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Custom_Status).

Adding the following function (adapted to your custom status) to `functions.php` solved this problem for me:

```
/**
 * Register custom post status: license
 */
function register_custom_post_status_license() {
    $custom_status = 'license';
    $count_label = 'License <span class="count">(%s)</span>';

    register_post_status( $custom_status, array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'License', 'post' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( $count_label, $count_label ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status_license' );
```